# Joomla URL redirect?

Tags: url, joomla

I am moving an old site to a Joomla site and when I redid the site, the page URL's changed.

Old URL:

http://www.wengerswanderers.com/bransontour.html

New URL:

http://www.wengerswanderers.com/branson-tour

Is there a way that the old URL (www.wengerswanderers.com/bransontour.html) be redirected to the new URL (www.wengerswanderers.com/branson-tour) so they will not lose their rankings in the search engines?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^bransontour.html http://www.wengerswanderers.com/branson-tour [R=301]
```

Have a look [here](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php) for Redirect 301 meaning.

Although, it seems that [some PR loss](http://www.marketingpilgrim.com/2010/03/google-confirms-301-redirects-result-in-pagerank-loss.html) is still inevitable with Redirect 301, too. But I don't think there's a best solution.

Comment: I accessed the .htaccess file and added the code like this:


RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^bransontour.html http://www.wengerswanderers.com/branson-tour [R=301]


It is not working. Does it take a little time for it to happen?

Comment: No. It's immediate! Post your `.htaccess` file as part of your question. Using Joomla, it's likely there was some content that interfere with the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Use com_redirect.
You can go in and manually enter the from and to for as many urls as you want to forward.